# (Java) Why does this compile: trivial final class does not implement abstract methods from inherited abstract parent

Tags: java, compilation

Why does this compile? (tried under both Oracle java 5 & java 6 (yes, I know, I'm slow to adapt)

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void methodA(String abc);

    public abstract String methodB(String abc);
}

public final class ConcreteClass
extends BaseClass
{
}
```

Just pop those two classes into separate files, call the javac on them and *poof*, they compile.  Since abstract methods are intended to be implemented by implementors, this doesn't make sense.  Playing with this a bit further, I only receive a compile error when a chunk of code attempts to call the unimplemented method.

So again, my question here is, does anyone know *WHY* the compiler allows this (or why we would want it to do this)?

Additional comment:

- When I did initial testing, I originally didn't have the ConcreteClass marked as final, and it occurred to me that another class could extend the class and thus, the complier might not complain and assume that you would have some other class later on down the road take care of it, but marking the class as final should make it pretty clear that this is not the case.

Comment: I doubt you have imported wrong version of `BaseClass`, It [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/Y4T2x)

Comment: Jigar - Thanks for looking at this. I set it up a bit differently, and I'm now wondering what, if anything within the setup is causing it.  I'm using Eclipse to edit, but that's not a big deal.  I'm using Windows 7 and compiling on the command line using javac <java file>.  Neither file has any package statements or import statements....<time passes>...ok, figured it out.  There must be some other class named BaseClass as part of the Java SDK.  Changing the BaseClass to SomeCrazyNameNoOneThoughtOf yields the compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jigar has mentioned in the comment, you must be importing wrong version of `BaseClass`. When I 
tried to compile your code, I get following error:

```
/Users/ShirishP/Desktop/ConcreteClass.java:1: ConcreteClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method methodB(java.lang.String) in BaseClass
public final class ConcreteClass extends BaseClass
             ^
1 error
```

Comment: I tend to agree.  Dan should erase all .class files and do a completely fresh compile.

Comment: See comment above, this was slightly occluded by an environment issue.

Answer (score -1):

It may not be intentional. The code that statically complains about abstract classes may be run when method calls are compiled, not when a class is declared (since calling the method is the potentially-bad part, not not declaring it). It's definitely something they could add, but it wouldn't catch anything useful so they may have figured it wasn't worth it.

Comment: I disagree this would definitely be useful.  I think it as others (Jigar & Garbage) have said a versioning issue.

Comment: The *compiler* code that checks for unimplemented abstract methods in non-abstract classes executes when the class is compiled, as several respondents have shown. You are conflating compile time with runtime checks such as lead to `AbstractMethodError`.

Comment: @EJP - I'm not conflating the two, I was just wrong. I've written compilers and I did mean the "code that statically complains about abstract classes" in the compiler - but as it's been pointed out, there is in fact code that checks the class declaration.